# Chrome extension not installing: CRX_HEADER_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I updated some code in an unlisted extension I am managing, published it to the store as usual, and it has successfully updated the version number.

When I attempt to install it, I get:
Package is invalid: 'CRX_HEADER_INVALID'.

The crx file is created for me, as per the docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/faq/#creating-a-listing

... I just upload the zip file containing my extension's code, as such I don't know what to do. I checked it is crx3 and it is. I am running Chrome Version 88.0.4324.96. I tried to install the previous version that was on the store, and the same package is invalid pop up appears, so the only thing I can think is that the issue could be down to how this crx file is created from my zip. Not sure how I would go about dealing with this, or if someone else had had this issue maybe they know whats going on?

EDIT: Have tried it on multiple versions of Chrome, same outcome on all. Believe the issue is with the conversion to crx file, but am yet to identify what the issue is.

Comment: If you install it directly from the webstore page then it definitely looks like a bug in Chrome which you can report on https://crbug.com. But if you download the crx file and then install it, the problem is in the downloader.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I tried downloading from the webstore's "Add to Chrome" button.

Comment: However that button triggers the cxr file download and then is automatically installed (if working). I'll raise a ticket on the link provided. Thank you

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you have an antivirus that tampers with the downloaded file? Try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: No, that is not the issue, but good call - I didn't think to try that

Answer (score 0):

I had to migrate to Manifest V3 in order to fix this.

The Google documentation "Introducing Manifest V3" did not state anywhere that migration was a required step in order to update an extension that was already on the store.